# Twilio Voice - Remove or change hangup tone

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm currently consuming Twilio from the JavaScript SDK on the frontend and the Twilio TwiML NodeJS library.

I've been looking for a way of avoiding the HANGUP tone at the end of voice calls.
Even changing it to a better sound would work for me.
Do you guys have any idea if this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Dude, google and read the docs.

The device sounds can be set using the [`deviceOptions.sounds` properties](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#deviceoptionssounds-properties-and-default-sounds).

If you are using version 1, the [options can be found here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/overview-1x-deprecated/device#available-sound-properties).

Comment: Yeah, that should do the trick. Somehow I did not arrive to those docs in my two months of working with Twilio.

And here's the link to the v2 API https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#deviceoptions